# Value lookup in Redis 2.4

Tags: python, redis, legacy-code

I need to list the keys that contain a certain value. Normally I would use the **SCAN** command, but the problem is that my client is using **Redis server version 2.4.14** and updating is not an option (legacy app with a lot of hacks might break).

What would you guys do? I'm using "redis" python client.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need that list just once, or on an ongoing basis?

Comment: Once a week is fine (just for deleting unuseful data). Could be a batch process.

Comment: In that case, given the above limitations, I suggest you take a dump of the db and process it using a newer version of Redis or even entirely offline with rdb-tools.

Comment: Will it be more effective than dumping all keys and doing the search in Python?